# Create Jax2b marshaller Formatted_Output property doesnt work

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

Im trying to create a Marshaller with Jax2b with a formatted output property:

```
protected static Marshaller createMarshaller() throws AMLParseException {
    final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();   
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(CAEXFile.class);             
    final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    props.put(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); //:TODO

    //marshaller.setJaxbContextProperties(props);

    return marshaller;
}
```

If i set the JaxbContextProperties it says "Property "jaxb.formatted.output" is not supported" :

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Eigenschaft "jaxb.formatted.output" wird nicht unterstützt.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:118) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:251) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromClasses(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:551) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:503) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

If i dont set the Property it works.
Any clue how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(Collections.singletonMap(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE ));
```